# Set default for folder parameter in QGIS processing scripts

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, parameters, file-path

In QGIS processing scripts we can define a folder as input parameter as follows:

```
[...define input/output parameters...]
##mypath=folder
[...rest of the script...]
```

**Question: Is it possible (and if yes, how) to set a default value for mypath?**

According to the approach for setting defaults for string input parameters

```
#'spam' is the default here
##egg=string spam
```

I tried various things like

```
##mypath=folder C:\tmp
##mypath=folder C:\\tmp
##mypath=folder 'C:\\tmp'
```

but none of them seems to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default paths for folders in **QGIS 3.0**:

[image: Script]